# babel-jest to transform non .js|.jsx extensions

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I have `Customer.js.flow` type file.

When I run jest, it fails with this error:

```
Customer.js.flow:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export type Customer = {
                                                                                         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:320:12)
```

Even if I explicitly added:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js.flow$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
},
```

and when I change `Customer.js.flow` to `Customer.js` I don't have the issue anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using `transform` in your jest settings, it will overwrite the default. [From the docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string):

> Note: if you are using the babel-jest transformer and want to use an
>   additional code preprocessor, keep in mind that when "transform" is
>   overwritten in any way the babel-jest is not loaded automatically
>   anymore. If you want to use it to compile JavaScript code it has to be
>   explicitly defined. See babel-jest plugin

So you need to as the matcher for `.js` files as well.

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js\\.flow$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
},
```

I'm not that good as regex but this  of cause can be simplified into one statement.

Comment: Updated my question, it wasn't this. I turns out solution is here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2152#issuecomment-262485964
So I wrote my own custom-transformer here: https://github.com/MayasHaddad/flow-jest-transformer